# What is the default serif, sans-serif and monospace font-family for Mac OS X?

Tags: fonts

Beginning with OS X 10.0 *Cheetah*, and assuming they are the same through the current release 10.8 *Mountain Lion*, what are the default fonts rendered for the following font-families?

- `font-family: serif;`
- `font-family: sans-serif;`
- `font-family: monospace;`

Comment: I would have thought it would be... "What are the default fonts for _[insert browser here]_", rather than the OS per se?

Comment: Nope, the OS is responsible for supplying the default fonts. In one case that I've tested, Firefox > 10 will render Courier New in place of Courier on Windows Systems -- probably because Courier is an old bitmap font which refuses to anti-alias.

Comment: I should clarify my reply above. The browser most definitely has an *option* to *choose* which font it uses as a default, depending upon the OS it's installed on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default fonts for WebKit/Safari under Mac OS X are as follows:

- Monospace -> Courier
- Sans-serif -> Helvetica
- Serif -> Times
- Standard (default) -> Times

This is gleaned directly from the [WebKit source](http://www.webkit.org/), specifically the XML/plist file at `Source/WebCore/Resources/DefaultFont.plist.in` that's [available online here](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/Resources/DefaultFonts.plist.in?rev=114895). It includes the following lines:

```
<dict>
  <key>monospace</key>
  <string>Courier</string>
  <key>standard</key>
  <string>Times</string>
  <key>sans-serif</key>
  <string>Helvetica</string>
  <key>serif</key>
  <string>Times</string>
</dict>
```

The same file also includes the default monospace, sans-serif, and serif fonts for Korean, Japanese, Simplified Chinese, and Traditional Chinese, if those are of any interest to you.

Comment: The sans-serif font, Helvetica, is usually San Francisco now. You can also just use `-apple-system` which may be changed to `system` soon ([source](https://webkit.org/blog/3709/using-the-system-font-in-web-content/))